# Find multiple maximum values in a 2d array fast

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, max

The situation is as follows:

I have a 2D numpy array. Its shape is (1002, 1004). Each element contains a value between 0 and Inf. What I now want to do is determine the first 1000 maximum values and store the corresponding indices in to a list named x and a list named y. This is because I want to plot the maximum values and the indices actually correspond to real time x and y position of the value.

What I have so far is:

```
x = numpy.zeros(500)
y = numpy.zeros(500)

for idx in range(500):
    x[idx] = numpy.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[0]
    y[idx] = numpy.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[1]
    full[full == full.max()] = 0.

print os.times()
```

Here full is my 2D numpy array. As can be seen from the for loop, I only determine the first 500 maximum values at the moment. This however already takes about 5 s. For the first 1000 maximum values, the user time should actually be around 0.5 s. I've noticed that a very time consuming part is setting the previous maximum value to 0 each time. How can I speed things up?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you use numpy 1.8?  It has the functions `partition` and `argpartition`.  I used the latter in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't use numpy 1.8. Isn't `partition` similar to `unique`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have numpy 1.8, you can use the [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) function or method.
Here's a script that calculates `x` and `y`:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array to work with.
np.random.seed(123)
full = np.random.randint(1, 99, size=(8, 8))

# Get the indices for the largest `num_largest` values.
num_largest = 8

indices = (-full).argpartition(num_largest, axis=None)[:num_largest]
# OR, if you want to avoid the temporary array created by `-full`:
# indices = full.argpartition(full.size - num_largest, axis=None)[-num_largest:]

x, y = np.unravel_index(indices, full.shape)

print("full:")
print(full)
print("x =", x)
print("y =", y)
print("Largest values:", full[x, y])
print("Compare to:    ", np.sort(full, axis=None)[-num_largest:])
```

Output:

```
full:
[[67 93 18 84 58 87 98 97]
 [48 74 33 47 97 26 84 79]
 [37 97 81 69 50 56 68  3]
 [85 40 67 85 48 62 49  8]
 [93 53 98 86 95 28 35 98]
 [77 41  4 70 65 76 35 59]
 [11 23 78 19 16 28 31 53]
 [71 27 81  7 15 76 55 72]]
x = [0 2 4 4 0 1 4 0]
y = [6 1 7 2 7 4 4 1]
Largest values: [98 97 98 98 97 97 95 93]
Compare to:     [93 95 97 97 97 98 98 98]
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the coolest algorithmic addition to 1.8. Although it's kind of obvious from the example, and it wasn't a requirement in the OP's question, it's probably worth stressing that the `partition` functions do not order the chunks into which they partition the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the array as @Inspired suggests, but looping through NumPy arrays item-by-item tends to lead to slower-performing code than code which uses NumPy functions since the NumPy functions are written in C/Fortran, while the item-by-item loop tends to use Python functions.

So, although sorting is `O(n log n)`, it may be quicker than a Python-based one-pass `O(n)` solution. Below `np.unique` performs the sort:

```
import numpy as np

def nlargest_indices(arr, n):
    uniques = np.unique(arr)
    threshold = uniques[-n]
    return np.where(arr >= threshold)

full = np.random.random((1002,1004))
x, y = nlargest_indices(full, 10)
print(full[x, y])
print(x)
# [  2   7 217 267 299 683 775 825 853]
print(y)
# [645 621 132 242 556 439 621 884 367]
```

---

Here is a timeit benchmark comparing `nlargest_indices` (above) to

```
def nlargest_indices_orig(full, n):
    full = full.copy()
    x = np.zeros(n)
    y = np.zeros(n)

    for idx in range(n):
        x[idx] = np.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[0]
        y[idx] = np.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[1]
        full[full == full.max()] = 0.
    return x, y


In [97]: %timeit nlargest_indices_orig(full, 500)
1 loops, best of 3: 5 s per loop

In [98]: %timeit nlargest_indices(full, 500)
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop
```

For timeit purposes I needed to copy the array inside `nlargest_indices_orig`, lest `full` get mutated by the timing loop.

Benchmarking the copying operation:

```
def base(full, n):
    full = full.copy()

In [102]: %timeit base(full, 500)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.11 ms per loop
```

shows this added about 4ms to the 5s benchmark for `nlargest_indices_orig`.

---

**Warning**: `nlargest_indices` and `nlargest_indices_orig` may return different results if `arr` contains repeated values.

`nlargest_indices` finds the `n` largest values in `arr` and then returns the `x` and `y` indices corresponding to the locations of those values.

`nlargest_indices_orig` finds the `n` largest values in `arr` and then returns **one** `x` and `y` index for each large value. If there is more than one `x` and `y` corresponding to the same large value, then some locations where large values occur may be missed.

They also return indices in a different order, but I suppose that does not matter for your purpose of plotting.

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you very much! I do have identical maximum values in my 2D array but have not encountered any problems

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the indices of the n max/min values in the 2d array, my solution (for largest is)

```
indx = divmod((-full).argpartition(num_largest,axis=None)[:3],full.shape[0])
```

This finds the indices of the largest values from the flattened array and then determines the index in the 2d array based on the remainder and mod.

Nevermind. Benchmarking shows the unravel method is twice as fast at least for num_largest = 3.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that the most time-consuming part is recalculating maximum. In fact, you have to calculate maximum of 1002*1004 numbers 500 times which gives you 500 million comparisons.

Probably you should write your own algorithm to find the solution in one pass: keep only 1000 greatest numbers (or their indices) somewhere while scanning your 2D array (without modifying the source array). I think that some sort of a binary heap (have a look at [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)) would suit for the storage.