# How can I find the n maximum values above a certain threshold in a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Preface: I'm building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20826735/109941).

In consideration of the code below:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array to work with.
np.random.seed(123)
full = np.random.randint(1, 99, size=(8, 8))

# Get the indices for the largest `num_largest` values.
num_largest = 8

indices = (-full).argpartition(num_largest, axis=None)[:num_largest]
# OR, if you want to avoid the temporary array created by `-full`:
# indices = full.argpartition(full.size - num_largest, axis=None)[-num_largest:]

x, y = np.unravel_index(indices, full.shape)

print "full:"
print full
print "x =", x
print "y =", y
print "Largest values:", full[x, y]
```

Output:

```
full:
[[67 93 18 84 58 87 98 97]
 [48 74 33 47 97 26 84 79]
 [37 97 81 69 50 56 68  3]
 [85 40 67 85 48 62 49  8]
 [93 53 98 86 95 28 35 98]
 [77 41  4 70 65 76 35 59]
 [11 23 78 19 16 28 31 53]
 [71 27 81  7 15 76 55 72]]
x = [0 2 4 4 0 1 4 0]
y = [6 1 7 2 7 4 4 1]
Largest values: [98 97 98 98 97 97 95 93]
```

How can I find the largest values **above** a certain threshold?

In other words, if I'm interested in returning only the values above '95', for example, how would I do that?

Desired Output:

```
Largest values: [98 97 98 98 97 97] # 95 and 93 are missing because it's below the threshold
```

In addition to filtering, I'd like to preserve the index information; that is, the x and y coordinates of the max values.

Hence, the solution below won't work because it simply filters the values at the end and sheds the index information.

```
full[full>95]
```

Comment: Use a masked array. indices = (-numpy.ma.masked_less_equal(full, 95)).argpartition(...).  Then indices.mask = numpy.ma.nomask.  The rest is unchanged.