# How to find lowest 3 values in a matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, minimum

So i have this fucntion to find the lowest value in a matrix, and return its position in the matrix, ie its indices:

```
final_matrix=[[3.57 2.71 9.2 5.63]
              [4.42 1.4 3.53 8.97]
              [1.2 0.33 6.26 7.77]
              [6.36 3.6 8.91 7.42]
              [1.59 0.9 2.4 4.24]] # this changes in my code, im just giving a very simple version of it here

def lowest_values(final_matrix):
best_value=10000 #or any arbitrarily high number 
    for i in range(0,len(final_matrix[:,0])):
        for j in range(0,len(final_matrix[0,:])):
            if final_matrix[i,j]<best_value:
                best_value=final_matrix[i,j]
                lowest_val_i=i
                lowest_val_j=j
    return(lowest_val_i, lowest_val_j)
```

this returns me (1,2), which just by visual analysis is correct. i want to now find the lowest 3 values - hopefully, to build into this loop. But i really cannot think how! Or at least i dont know how to implement it. I was thinking of some if-else loop, that if the lowest value is already found, then 'void' this one and found 2nd lowest, and then same thing to find the third. But im not sure.

Please dont be too quick to shut this question down - im very new to programming, and very stuck!

Comment: `final_matrix[0,:]` is not valid. `0,` is a tuple. How is it returning you `(1, 2)`?

Comment: Is `final_matrix` actually a 2D numpy array?

Comment: From the PO  present, I suspect he is looking for numpy solution. Not pure Python.

Answer (score 1):

### The human Approach

I think my approach to this is different enough from different answers to share.

I am only doing 3 comparisons for every list element so it should be O(n). Also I'm not creating a entirely new list with (value, indices) tuple of all the elements.

```
matrix=[[3.57, 2.71, 9.2, 5.63],
              [4.42, 1.4, 3.53, 8.97],
              [1.2, 0.33, 6.26, 7.77],
              [6.36, 3.6, 8.91, 7.42],
              [1.59, 0.9, 2.4, 4.24]]
              
            
def compare_least_values(value, i, j):
    global least
    if value < least[2][0] :
        if value < least[1][0] :
            if value < least[0][0] :
                least.insert(0, (value,(i,j)))
            else:
                least.insert(1, (value,(i,j)))
        else:
            least.insert(2, (value,(i,j)))
    

def lowest_three_values(matrix): 
    global least
    least = [(10000, (None, None)), (10000, (None, None)), (10000, (None, None))]  
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, value in enumerate(row):
            compare_least_values(value, i, j)
    return least[:3]
    
print(lowest_three_values(matrix))
```

#### Output:

```
[(0.33, (2, 1)), (0.9, (4, 1)), (1.2, (2, 0))]
```

### The practical approach (Numpy)

If you're familiar with numpy than this is the way to go. Even if you're not it can be use as a copy-paste snippet.

```
import numpy as np

matrix=[[3.57, 2.71, 9.2, 5.63],
              [4.42, 1.4, 3.53, 8.97],
              [1.2, 0.33, 6.26, 7.77],
              [6.36, 3.6, 8.91, 7.42],
              [1.59, 0.9, 2.4, 4.24]]
matrix = np.array(matrix)

indices_1d = np.argpartition(matrix, 3, axis=None)[:3]
indices_2d = np.unravel_index(indices_1d, matrix.shape)
least_three = matrix[indices_2d]

print('least three values : ', least_three)
print('indices : ', *zip(*indices_2d) )
```

#### Output:

```
least three values :  [0.33 0.9  1.2 ] 
indices :  (2, 1) (4, 1) (2, 0)
```

See this [Stackoverflow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825990/find-multiple-maximum-values-in-a-2d-array-fast) for detailed answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand that return thing (1,2). Lowest value of matrix is 0.33. and that's position is (2,1).

So my solution for your code;

```
all_items = []
# i appended matrix's all items to one list
for row in final_matrix:
    for i in row:
        all_items.append(i)
# and i sorted that list as from min to max
all_items.sort()
# then i took first 3 values
lowest_3 = all_items[0:3]
positions = []
# and i append their positions that's in the matrix into positions
for i in lowest_3:
    for row in range(len(final_matrix)):
        if(i in final_matrix[row]):
            positions.append([row, final_matrix[row].index(i)])
            break

# lowest_3  = [0.33, 0.9, 1.2]
# positions = [[2, 1], [4, 1], [2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
final_matrix=[[3.57, 2.71, 9.2, 5.63],
              [4.42, 1.4, 3.53, 8.97],
              [1.2, 0.33, 6.26, 7.77],
              [6.36, 3.6, 8.91, 7.42],
              [1.59, 0.9, 2.4, 4.24]]

min_values = []
for i in range(3):
    mini = final_matrix[0][0]
    for row in final_matrix:
        for n in row:
            if n < mini:
                mini = n
                n_index = row.index(n)
                row_index = final_matrix.index(row)
    min_values.append(mini)
    del final_matrix[row_index][n_index]


print("Finals {}".format(min_values))
```

Let me explains you:
The first loop through how many min values you want (change it, you will see what I mean)
the second and the last one, loop through the matrix to take the minimun value
The line `del final_matrix[row_index][n_index]` will destroy the minimal number IN the original matrix
So if you want the keep the original matrix you have to create a new one and copy the original in => use deepcopy() from the copy module

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the N smallest items from a list of items (or a "matrix" in this case) and when N is small you can do better than sorting the items of your list by creating a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html), which takes linear time and then by popping the N smallest elements which is an O(log N) operation for each pop. The `heap queue` is an important data structure, which you should study.

```
import heapq

final_matrix=[[3.57, 2.71, 9.2, 5.63],
              [4.42, 1.4, 3.53, 8.97],
              [1.2, 0.33, 6.26, 7.77],
              [6.36, 3.6, 8.91, 7.42],
              [1.59, 0.9, 2.4, 4.24]]

def lowest_values(final_matrix):
    # create a flat list, l, from the matrix
    # each element is a tuple: (value, x-coordinate, y-coordinate)
    l = [(final_matrix[x][y], x, y)
        for x in range(len(final_matrix))
            for y in range(len(final_matrix[0]))
        ]
    heapq.heapify(l) # O(N) time
    for _ in range(3):
        # pop next smallest tuple:
        value, x, y = heapq.heappop(l) # O(log N) time
        print(f'value={value}, x={x}, y={y}')

lowest_values(final_matrix)
```

Prints:

```
value=0.33, x=2, y=1
value=0.9, x=4, y=1
value=1.2, x=2, y=0
```

**Note**

The above code could have been simplified to the following, which is probably even slightly more efficient if all you want are the 3 smallest items and then you have no further need for the heap queue structure. But I wanted to show the two basic operations of creating a heap queue from a list and then successively producing the smallest items from that heap queue:

```
import heapq

final_matrix=[[3.57, 2.71, 9.2, 5.63],
              [4.42, 1.4, 3.53, 8.97],
              [1.2, 0.33, 6.26, 7.77],
              [6.36, 3.6, 8.91, 7.42],
              [1.59, 0.9, 2.4, 4.24]]

def lowest_values(final_matrix):
    # create a flat list, l, from the matrix
    # each element is a tuple: (value, x-coordinate, y-coordinate)
    l = [(final_matrix[x][y], x, y)
        for x in range(len(final_matrix))
            for y in range(len(final_matrix[0]))
        ]
    for value, x, y in heapq.nsmallest(3, l):
        print(f'value={value}, x={x}, y={y}')

lowest_values(final_matrix)
```